# Custom ServiceAuthorizationManager and WcfCommunicationListener service fabric

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm developing a service fabric stateful service with internal wcf endpoint, and i need to create some authorization validation, searching in foruns i've seen that i can create a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager and link to my wcf service behavior.

My question is, can i link my custom `ServiceAuthorizationManager` to my wcf service fabric behavior ?

I am creating a Communication Listener Wcf as follows:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new List<ServiceReplicaListener>
        {
            new ServiceReplicaListener(this.CreateWcfCommunicationListener)
        };


    }


private WcfCommunicationListener<IMainBusService> CreateWcfCommunicationListener(StatefulServiceContext context)
{
    var wcfCommunicationListener = new WcfCommunicationListener<IMainBusService>(
         serviceContext: context,
         wcfServiceObject: this,
         // For this example, we will be using NetTcpBinding.
         listenerBinding: GetNetTcpBinding(),
         endpointResourceName: "WcfServiceEndpoint");
    return wcfCommunicationListener;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before returning wcfCommunicationListener do the following:

```
wcfCommunicationListener.ServiceHost.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new CustomServiceAuthorizationManager();
```